# Excel 2010 Formula with and without blanks calculated

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
S   AM  PM  E   NO. USED
8   2   2   6   6
6           3   3
```

I am stuck and just cannot figure this one out.

I am working on a spreadsheet for inventory (col A-E; rows 1,2).

`S` is start of day, `AM` if 1st shift adding pieces to inventory, `PM` is the 2nd shift adding pieces, and `E` is the inventory taken at the end of the day.

In Column `E` is No of pieces used (or taken out of inventory).  I cannot get it all to come out to the appropriate answers E1=6 and E2=3 with no pieces produced and added to the inventory. Look forward to the help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple + and - in your formula in a new column:
In F2 write `=A2+B2+C2-E2` and drag it down

Another formula is to calculate the sum of initial quantity(S) and the added pieces (AM, PM)
In F2 write `=Sum(A2:C2)-E2` and you will get same result, you can drag it down